# UIAlertView not returning appropriate value

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uialertview, uialertcontroller

Here is my code

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Alert: UIViewController {


class func showAlert(title: String, message: String, buttonTitle: String? = nil, buttonTitle2: String? = nil, sender: UIViewController) -> Int? {
    var flag : Int?
    func yes(){
        flag = 1

    }
    func no(){
        flag = 0

    }
     //= nil  ;
    if objc_getClass("UIAlertController") != nil {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        if (buttonTitle != nil){
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            yes()


        }))
        }
        if (buttonTitle2 != nil)  {
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle2, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                no()

            }))
        }


        sender.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

       return flag


    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = title
        alert.message = message
        alert.addButtonWithTitle(buttonTitle)
        alert.addButtonWithTitle(buttonTitle2)
        print("inside Else")

        alert.show()
        return flag
        //make and use a UIAlertView
    }

}


}
```

The problem is that the flag getting returned is always nil to the view controller I call Alert from. I need the flag to return 1 if "yes" is pressed and 0 if "No" is pressed. I have been stuck in this problem for lot of time. Help.

Comment: It's a `UIAlertController`. The `UIAlertView` is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code,

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func showAlert() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hey there", message: "Do you want to do it?", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let btnAction1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default) { (action : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        self.yes()
    }

    let btnAction2 = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Default) { (action : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        self.no()
    }

    alertController.addAction(btnAction1)
    alertController.addAction(btnAction2)

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func yes() -> Int
{
    print("Yes")
    return 1
}

func no() -> Int
{
    print("No")
    return 0
}
}
```

Its working fine here, i hope it will work for u also.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake that closure won't execute until button clicked but function will return right now.You should deliver a closure to this function.It will look like:

```
class func showAlert(title: String, message: String, buttonTitle: String? = nil, buttonTitle2: String? = nil, sender: UIViewController,handler: ((Bool) -> Void)) -> Void
```

And handle it in alert action like this:

```
handler(true)
```

Comment: How do I add a default value to the handler  cause showAlert is getting called in many cases and all don't need a return value?

Comment: Even if I don't pass the handler parameter , show alert should get executed.

Comment: @DarthVader You should handle your click action in closure,if you can't do this,use closure to pass this action.Remember this.